# Safely access objects in Python without try / catch

Tags: python, idioms, accessor

In Objective-C you can do `[variable valueForKeyPath:@"abc.def"]` or `[[variable abc] def]` and if  `abc` doesn't exist on `variable` you'll get a `nil` value in the end and will not get an error or exception. This is really convenient.  Is there something like this in Python? I know you can do (for dictionaries at least)

```
abc = variable.get('abc', None)
if abc:
    def = abc.get('def', None)
```

or

```
try:
    def = variable.get('abc').get('def')
except:
    pass
```

which seems incredibly verbose. Is there an easier way when I just want to access an object's attribute or get a None value back?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo.

Comment: This forgiving behavior leads to bugs only.

Comment: Your second ObjC expression _does_ in fact crash if `abc` is not a method of `variable`. You may be thinking of the fact that the _reciever_ of a message (here, `variable`) being `nil` does not cause a crash.

Comment: It's somewhat counter-intuitive coming from languages like Java, where we spend all this time getting frustrated with exceptions and trying to hide / compartmentalize error behavior, but in Python, you'll write better, more robust, and easier to read code with try-except blocks.  It's a central aspect of Pythonic programming: http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams +10 if I could for the comment. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @JoshCaswell yes you will get a crash if the object does not response to selector `abc`. However you won't if calling `abc` simply returns nil, which is the use case here. 
@IgnacioVazquez-Abrams lol, great answer. totally cracked me me.

Comment: You said «if abc doesn't exist on variable».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about

```
def = variable.get('abc', {}).get('def',None)
```

well, this will only work for dict..

Answer (score 3):

You can use nested calls to `getattr`:

```
def = getattr( getattr(variable, 'abc', None), 'def', None)
```

You can also dispense with the methods, and just catch the `AttributeError`

```
try:
    def = variable.abc.def
except AttributeError:
    def = None
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no short built-in syntax for what you want.  You might want to write a helper function that does this for you, or a `collections.defaultdict` might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Python avoids this behavior by design because it can lead to bugs that are difficult to diagnose. By raising an exception, the programmer is forced to either explicitly request a default value with dict.get(), getattr(), etc. or otherwise handle the case that the lookup fails. The program stops exactly where the error occurred in the program.

In the case of Objective C (as well as PHP, which is notoriously unpleasant to debug), the program may continue for a long time before you realize that your variable has been set incorrectly. Generally the longer it has been since the error occurred, the more difficult it will be to find the cause. THIS is inconvenient.

Comment: I agree in the general case hiding error is not desirable. However in this specific case the intended behavior is exactly to retrieve an attribute or `None`. Having a syntax or shortcut that's explicitly for this purpose should do more good than harm.

Comment: Agreed; that's exactly what getattr() and dict.get() provide.